# primeng <p-dropdown> get previous selected value

Tags: javascript, angular, select, dropdown, primeng

I want to get the previous selected value in primeng dropdown .

```
<p-dropdown [options]="options" [filter]="true" [(ngModel)]="selectedType" (onChange)="onSelectType($event)" formControlName="alertType"></p-dropdown>
```

On change event I want to check whether the selected type is valid using an api, but need to revert if it is invalid. Since I am using ngModel, the value of selectedType is changing whenever the dropdown value changes.

So how can I get the previous selected value?

Comment: store it as a window variable is an option, as it makes it a global js var. That would be the easiest solution

Comment: I Just posted answer for what u expected previous value and selected value  . i think its helpful

Comment: Yes. Actually the ngModelChange made this as the answer which I was searching for. Thanks man.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This sample example of ngModelChange :

**app.component.html**

```
<p-dropdown [options]="cities" [(ngModel)]="selectedCity" (ngModelChange)="onSelectType($event)"></p-dropdown>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { SelectItem } from 'primeng/primeng';

export class AppComponent {
    cities: SelectItem[];
    selectedCity: any;
    previousVal: any;
    currentVal: any;

    constructor() {
        this.cities = [{
            "label": "London",
            "value": "london"
        }, {
            "label": "USA",
            "value": "usa"
        }];
    }

   onSelectType(event) {
       if(event) {
           this.previousVal = this.currentVal;
           this.currentVal = event;
       }
       console.log('this.previousVal', this.previousVal);
       console.log('this.currentVal', this.currentVal);
   }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { DropdownModule } from 'primeng/primeng';

imports: [ DropdownModule ]
```

solution is use **ngModelChange**;

Comment: Just one small note, the syntax `[(ngModel)]` is actually `[ngModel]` and `(ngModelChange)` so you might want to take out the parentheses on `ngModel` if you want to implement `ngModelChange`

Comment: Wish I could upvote this more. This wasn't mentioned nowhere in PrimeNG documentation!

Comment: U don't need `if(event) {`